# free image hosting with the ability to get the url

Tags: android, image, hosting

I have about ~200 images that I want to use in my android app. I want to upload them to any hosting service and then load them using Glide.
after uploading the images I want them all to have the same base URL for example www.hosting.come/myprofile and append the file name to it.

I have tried to do so with Google firebase and imgur.com and imagebb.com but none of them work for me.
any ideas?

Comment: Why does Firebase not work? That is what I would suggest, I use it for my app with 700 images, and it's completely free.

Comment: firebase doesn't allow me to choose the URL path to my picture. could you do it? and how?

Comment: I've written an answer showing you how to do it, it's super quick and easy with Firebase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily use Firebase's Cloud Storage for this.

1. Open up your Firebase console and navigate to your project.
2. Under "Develop", select "Storage".
3. (Optional) Create a folder called "images".
4. Click the "Upload file" button and select all your images.

This may take awhile to upload if you have a large number of images, but it'll work.

Now, within Android, you can fetch the url very easily.

```
// get a reference to your image whatever it's called   
val ref = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child("images/my_image_001.png")

// get the actual download Url and load it into your imageView
ref.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener {
    Glide.with(context)
        .load(it)
        .into(imageView)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all you have to create a images folder on your web hosting's account file manager.
Note: You have to create folder in **public_html** on your server.

**You have to add images as shown below.**

[image]

After that in your android project where you have load images by recyclerView or listview.

First of all Store your base url in strings.xml.

Like this:

```
<string name="host_url">https://laevorotatory-seesa.000webhostapp.com/wwol/</string>
<string name="image_url">https://laevorotatory-seesa.000webhostapp.com/wwol/product_images</string>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.Fragment_Home_User">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar_user_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/images_recyclerView_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.example.womenwalkoflife.R;
import com.example.womenwalkoflife.adapters.Adapter_Product_User;
import com.example.womenwalkoflife.objects.Product_User;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Objects;

public class Fragment_Home_User extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "HomeUser";
    private RecyclerView Images_RecyclerView;
    private Adapter_Images imageAdapter;
    private ArrayList<Image> imagesUrlList = new ArrayList<>();
    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment__home__user, container, false);
        progressBar = rootView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar_user_id);
        Images_RecyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.images_recyclerView_id);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        Images_RecyclerView.setRecycledViewPool(new RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool());
        Images_RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        imageAdapter = new Adapter_Images(this, imagesUrlList );
        Images_RecyclerView.setAdapter(ViewProduct_Adapter);
        GetAllImages();
        return rootView;
    }

    private void GetAllImages() {
        imagesUrlList.clear();
        String url = getString(R.string.host_url) + "getImages.php";

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                if (response != null) {
                    Log.e(TAG, response);
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("images_response");

                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                            JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            String imageName = obj.getString("image_name");

                            Image image = new Image(imageName);
                            imagesNameList.add(image);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Images_RecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    Images_RecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Images_RecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

**Create Class for Images:**

**Image.java**

```
public class Image {
    private String imageFileName;

    public Image(String imageFileName) {
        this.imageFileName = imageFileName;
    }

    public String getImageFileName() {
        return imageFileName;
    }

    public void setImageFileName(String imageFileName) {
        this.imageFileName = imageFileName;
    }
}
```

**Also create adapter to set values in recylerview:**

**Adapter_Images.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.womenwalkoflife.R;
import com.example.womenwalkoflife.objects.Image;
import com.squareup.picasso.MemoryPolicy;
import com.squareup.picasso.NetworkPolicy;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Adapter_Images extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter_Images.ImageViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<Image> imagesList;

    public Adapter_Images(Context context, ArrayList<Image> imagesList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.imagesList = imagesList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ImageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View rootView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_layout_images, parent, false);
        return new ImageViewHolder(rootView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ImageViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Image image = imagesList.get(position);

        String url = context.getString(R.string.image_url) + image.getImageFileName();

        Picasso.get().load(url).networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE).memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE).into(holder.imageView);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return imagesList.size();
    }

    static class ImageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView imageView;

        public ImageViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_id);
        }
    }
}
```

**row_layout_images.xml**

```
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/imageView_id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Now you have to only store images name into database using phpmyadmin and create a getImages.php file at server which returns names of images and store into **images_reponse** JSON array.

I hope this will help you better.